# Java: Adding 2 numbers with BufferReader, not working on CS Academy

Tags: java, for-loop, bufferedreader

I'm trying to add 2 integers together and print out the result, for a task on `CS Academy`. I'm using a BufferReader to read the integer results and an enhanced-for loop to put the values into A & B; however, it just provides a blank result. How do I fix the enhanced-for loop and the reader?
https://csacademy.com/contest/archive/task/addition/

--

task:
You are given two integer values A and B, compute and output their sum.

Standard input
The first line contains the two integers A and B.

Standard output
Output a single number representing the sum of A and B.

---

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.io.*;

  class Main {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
          int A, B;
          A =0; B =0;

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Integer:");
            int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int[] values = new int[i];
            for(int value: values ) {
            A=value[0];
            B=value[1];
            }
        System.out.println(A + B );

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your objective is. Can you describe a sample input and an expected output? Downvoting your question until then.

Comment: input: 2 3. Expected Output: 5

Comment: There is no such thing as 'adding 2 numbers with `BufferedReader`'. Try to describe your properly. It will also force you to think clearly *about* it.

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't work because first of all you are reading only one number instead of two. Secondly, you are adding two numbers which are initialized to 0 but which never get any other values. You expect user to enter two numbers separated by a space. Therefore, you need to split the input string ("10 15") with a space and then treat each individual one string as a number and then sum it up.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter Integer:");
String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ", 2);
System.out.println("Sum is " + (Integer.parseInt(str[0]) + Integer.parseInt(str[1])));
br.close();
```

Comment: Your method works for simple numbers but when you do Input:366 789. It doesn't work, nor does parse negatives well.

Comment: @ComputerGuy123, that's not right. It works for both the cases you described. Just run the code snippet I have given.

Comment: I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "883198518 "
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Main.main(Main.java:41)

Comment: Your input "883198518 " consists of only one number. That's why you get that error. Your input should contain exactly two numbers separated by a space.